# Struct variable not being updated

Tags: struct, go, channel

I have an array in test code

```
arr := []Server{}
```

which asks for arr[0].GetId()

Server is an interface.
ServerInstance is a struct implementing a method of interface, i.e

```
func (serv ServerInstance) GetId() int {
    return serv.Id
}
```

I have a goroutine like

```
func (serv *ServerInstance) someFunc
```

which is updating a variable 'Id' of struct. I am sure of value being updated as -

```
serv.Id=23445
```

But this is not being reflected in call at line 3

*Update***

```
for somecondition {
     arr=append(arr,FuncReturningServerIntercae() // calling this invokes goroutine which keeps updating `Id` very frequently
}


for {
   for _,s := range arr {
        print s.GetId()   // ** No Update **
     }
    sleep(some duration)
}
```

** Example **
http://play.golang.org/p/zUqJ0hEjxv

Comment: well you are sure, but you wiill have to show some code for somone to help

Comment: Which part do you doubt?

Comment: If the call at line 3 is in a separate goroutine, it's possible that your id hasn't been updated yet?

Comment: just after the assignmet `serv.Id=23445` , I printf to verify

Comment: There are a lot of things that could go wrong... It's hard to say without seeing a small, simple example. Can you boil it down to the relevant snippet and post the code or a link to play.golang.org or some such?

Comment: See example @ http://play.golang.org/p/zUqJ0hEjxv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're copying the structs when appending them, rather than placing pointers to the structs themselves in the example. http://play.golang.org/p/rQz9RLTzMU -- works as intended yes?
Further info: Golang is a pass-by-value language, so if you're using goroutines and you want to keep the sanctity of your data, you'd be better off using pointers.

Comment: I get "Snippet not found" from that link.